# Expose global API methods to control vue components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building an modular administrative interface for a web application. The core of the interface is a Vue application which uses different components, like a menu.

Since Vue is only one part of the application, i want to expose a global API to the browser. Those methods should be able to communicate with the Vue components, like the following example. The code is only for demonstration purposes.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import AdminMenu from './AdminMenu.js';

const application = () => {

    var app = document.createElement('div');
    app.id = 'app';
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(app);

    /**
     * Registers a new vue component via Vue.component(...)
     * Also creates a new '<admin-menu />' element in the app container
     */
    const adminMenu = new AdminMenu();

    const vueApp = new Vue({
        el: '#app'
    });

    return {
        addMenuItem(title, callback) {
            /**
             * adds the new item to the list of items in the
             * data array of the menu component
             */
            adminMenu.addItem(title, callback)
        }
    }

};

window.app = application();
```

Other (non-modular vanilla javascript) parts of the application should be able to access those methods like this:

```
window.app.addMenuItem('Say Hello', e => alert('Hi!'));
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: so your backend ist node.js ? you could build an api with the express module..I never mixed that before